# Exchange Active Sync email on Galaxy 10.1 disappears.

Tags: security, exchange, accounts, active-sync, stock-email-app

One of our reps has a Galaxy 10.1 and she has now for the 3rd time in two months complained about her corporate email disappearing, I’ve read a few of the posts here and on other sites and the one thing that keeps coming up is the security remote wipe that needs to be activated before the Active Sync setup completes, I doubt if the tech guys at our head office even knows how to wipe someone’s mail from a tablet, so my question is, is there any way to use Exchange Active Sync with the default email app but bypass the activation for the security policy?

Comment: Do you require ActiveSync or can basic Exchange or even IMAP protocol be used?

Comment: Active sync is the only other option on the tab we can select, we can use pop3 but the user has sub-folders that wont display with pop and imap is not secure enough according to the guy  who setup our exchange at head office.

Comment: IMAP is as secure as POP as long as you use encryption properly. But if you can't affect company policy, debating that is moot in this case.